# How To Use GKE IAM in k8s client-go

Tags: go, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, client-go

I am using k8s go client (https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go) to create jobs on GKE cluster (the code is running inside a pod). But I am having this error:

```
{
  "error": "2 UNKNOWN: jobs.batch is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:default:default\" cannot create resource \"jobs\" in API group \"batch\" in the namespace \"default\""
}
```

Looks like I am using `system:serviceaccount:default:default`, but how can I use a GCP IAM account instead?

I have already set up GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
following https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform. But looks like it only works with GCP client not with k8s client

Comment: At first glance it looks like your `serviceaccount` dont have permissions to create `job`. Did you create any [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) `ClusterRole` and `ClusterRoleBinding`? Could you share your job YAML? What Kubernetes version are you using? Also you are using `Google Kubernetes Engine` or you are using `Google Compute Engine` and you created cluster using `Minikube` or `Kubeadm`?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the [gcpAuthProvider plugin](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/20923fd71b14d068ee301eaf1c5320178b9ba585/plugin/pkg/client/auth/gcp/gcp.go#L58) when creating the [auth client](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/typed/authentication/v1#New).